# Nginx Websocket doesnot send a closing event

Tags: go, nginx, websocket

I made a websocket server in golang, I have implemented room system which stores the connection in map of room, It works perfectly in my local machine. When the client closes the connection the room is cleared and everything works fine. But When I do the same thing (close connection from client or the nginx times out) in server it gives an error.

**write tcp 127.0.0.1:6969->127.0.0.1:51966: write: broken pipe**

It happens just in the server.

My nginx Server config.

```
proxy_connect_timeout       3600s;
proxy_send_timeout          3600s;
proxy_read_timeout          3600s;
send_timeout                3600s;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
}
```

I have tired basically everything on the internet. But did not solve the issue.

Comment: Does it matter tat there's an error?

Comment: Yes, we are build a very high performance server and the instance that is not being cleared because of this error  catches up to us over time.